# sip conference call in android api level 9

Tags: android, sip

I saw there is SIP support in android 2.3. And I know that one can make conference calls in SIP.
But when I checked the API of android.net.sip I couldn't find any references to conference calls.
Are conference calls supported with android sip API?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, i haven't seen SIP Android documentation, but working on some 3rd party sip stack for Android and other platform,i believe, SIP provide framework for data transfer(voice and text ), Application has to be written on top of it, for data transfer....

Comment: How many participants do you have in mind? A cell phone may not have adequate CPU power and bandwidth for mixing and distributing the media of all participants to all participants... Regular SIP hardphones  usually do "three way calling", and delegate to a media server for more populous conferences.